# How to use native string in Retrofit header?

Tags: android, mobile, android-ndk, retrofit

I'm a newbie in the NDK world. I have a key placed in the C/C++ layer and I want to use it when I do a GET with Retrofit.

Here is my code

I have 2 .mk files but they are not relevant to my question and I have a keys.c file where I store the key:

```
#include <jni.h>
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_hello_world_PlacesListActivity_getNativeKey(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {
 return (*env)->  NewStringUTF(env, "my_key");
}
```

I'm able to read the key with this code in my PlacesListActivity:

```
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("keys");
}

public static native String getNativeKey();
```

and now I want to use the native String in the auth header of a GET request in a interface:

```
public interface TestService {
@Headers({
"client_id:" + PlacesListActivity.getNativeKey()
})
@GET("/some_end_point/")
}
```

The issue I'm getting is this:

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up modifying the way I pass the auth header

```
@GET("/some_end_point/")
Observable<PlaceLocations> getPlaces(@Header("client_id") String authKey,@Path("name") String name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing the interface and calling the C++ function from there. Interfaces are usually used to declare the function but not actually implement the function.